# Normalization of density operator in combined system in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, tensor-calculus, density-operator

If we consider a combined system of quantum systems $A$ and $B$ with probability density $\rho^{C} = \rho^{A} \otimes \rho^{B}$. If we measure system $A$ to be in state $|a_0⟩$. Then the state of the joint system would be  $$\tilde{\rho} = |a_0\rangle\langle a_0| \otimes \rho^B =\frac{(|a_0 \rangle \langle a_0 |)\rho^C(|a_0 \rangle \langle a_0 |)}{\mathcal{N}},$$ 
As I understand, the normalization $\mathcal{N}$ should be the total probability of the system being in state $|a_0 \rangle$, I'm just not sure how to go about obtaining this in quantity? I'm specifcally interested in $\mathcal{N}$ in terms of $\rho^{C
}$.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: $\mathcal{N}=\langle a_0|\rho^A|a_0\rangle$

Comment: @octonion Thanks for your response. Do you know what that would $\mathcal{N}$ would be in terms of $\rho^{c}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$\tilde{\rho} = \frac{|a_0 \rangle \langle a_0 | \,\rho^C\,|a_0 \rangle \langle a_0 |}{\mathcal{N}}\equiv \frac{\rho_{a0} \,\rho^C\,\rho_{a0}}{\mathcal{N}}$$
where I just wrote the projection operator $\rho_{a0}\equiv|a_0 \rangle \langle a_0 |$, to emphasize that this is itself a simple density operator.

Density matrices are normalized $\text{Tr} \tilde \rho = 1$, so
$$\mathcal{N} = {\text{Tr} \left[\rho_{a0} \,\rho^C\,\rho_{a_0}\right]}{}={\text{Tr} \left[\rho_{a0} \,\rho^C\right]},$$
where the second equality follows since $Tr[ABC]=Tr[CAB]$ and $\rho_{a0}^2=\rho_{a0}$.

This gives you $\mathcal{N}$ in terms of $\rho^C$ if for some reason you don't know the factors $\rho^A,\rho^B$ but still can deal with the operator $|a_0\rangle\langle a_0|$

Comment: Okay thanks for you answer, just two things, I understnad your reasoning, but in the text I am using it states that $\mathcal{N} = Tr[\langle a_0| \rho^C| a_0 \rangle]$ rather than $Tr[| a_0 \rangle \langle a_0| \rho^{C}|a_0 \rangle \langle a_0 |]$ which you have, do you know why this is? Also do you know why the probability of measuring $|a_0 \rangle$ is given by: $Pr(|a_0 \rangle) = Tr[\langle a_0| \rho^C| a_0 \rangle] =\mathcal{N}$ rather than just $\langle a_0| \rho^{C}| a_0 \rangle$ which is usually the case for a probability density operator?

Comment: $|a_0\rangle$ is a state living in the A Hilbert space. So when you take $\langle a_0| \rho^{C}| a_0 \rangle$ there's still an operator in the B Hilbert space left over, that's why the trace is necessary. Since the trace of the B part is just 1, it just reduces to my original comment on your question in terms of $\rho^A$. There is no difference of this from $Tr[\rho_{a0}\rho^C]$ as I wrote in my answer but in the latter you can generalize to any operator in place of $\rho_{a0}$ (not just projection on the pure state $a_0$) and it gives you the expectation in state $C$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand your reasoning for why $Pr(|a_0 \rangle) = Tr[\langle a_0| \rho^{C}| a_0 \rangle]$, but I'm having difficulty seeing exactly how to show this. If we consider $\rho^{C} = \rho^{A} \otimes \rho^{B} =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \rho^{A}_{11}\rho^{B} & \rho^{A}_{12}\rho^{B} \\
   \rho_{21}^{A}\rho^{B} & \rho_{22}^{A}\rho^{B} \\
  \end{array} } \right].$    
Would $\langle a_0| \rho^{C}|a_0 \rangle = \rho_{11}^{A}\rho^{B}$ and hence $Tr[\langle a_0| \rho^{C}|a_0 \rangle] = \rho_{11}^{A}Tr[\rho^{B}] = \rho_{11}^{A}$? Is this correct?

Comment: Assuming you are taking the $a_0$ state as the first component, yes that's correct.

Comment: Just to confirm one thing, in the case where we have some density operator $\rho$ is the probability that we end up in state $| m \rangle$ given by $p_m = \langle m| \rho | m \rangle = Tr[|m \rangle \langle m | \rho |m \rangle \langle m |] = Tr [\langle m | \rho | m \rangle]$. Are all these equations correct?

Comment: They are more or less all correct. Like we were talking earlier, if the state m is a state in one of the factor Hilbert spaces $\langle m|\rho|m\rangle$ might have an operator part left over like $\rho^A_{11}\rho^B$. So if we are being picky $Tr(\langle m|\rho|m\rangle)$ is the probability.